Can't activate sim card. Sim pin2 lock
I have an industrial PC(MBC-3200) with an integrated SIM card port.
I try to follow this tutorial and this one
Here's the result of mmcli -m 0:
  -----------------------------------
  General  |                    path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |               device id: 71ea5535d9ba0444769fb99feeea32508a0fa29c
  -----------------------------------
  Hardware |            manufacturer: Android
           |                   model: Android
           |       firmware revision: SLM750-V-MBIM_4.0.1_EQ101
           |          carrier config: ROW_Generic_3GPP
           | carrier config revision: 05010823
           |            h/w revision: 0
           |               supported: gsm-umts, lte, tds
           |                 current: gsm-umts, lte, tds
           |            equipment id: 864431063782348
  -----------------------------------
  System   |                  device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
           |                 physdev: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
           |                 drivers: cdc_mbim
           |                  plugin: generic
           |            primary port: cdc-wdm2
           |                   ports: cdc-wdm2 (mbim), wwan0 (net)
  -----------------------------------
  Status   |                    lock: sim-pin2
           |          unlock retries: sim-pin2 (3)
           |                   state: enabled
           |             power state: on
           |          signal quality: 0% (recent)
  -----------------------------------
  Modes    |               supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                          allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                          allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                          allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                          allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                          allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                          allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                 current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  -----------------------------------
  Bands    |               supported: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-4, utran-6, utran-5, 
           |                          utran-8, utran-2, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                          eutran-20, eutran-34, eutran-39, eutran-40, utran-19
           |                 current: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-4, utran-6, utran-5, 
           |                          utran-8, utran-2, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                          eutran-20, eutran-34, eutran-39, eutran-40, utran-19
  -----------------------------------
  IP       |               supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  -----------------------------------
  3GPP     |                    imei: 864431063782348
           |           enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |            registration: idle
  -----------------------------------
  SIM      |        primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
 

As you can see it says that the sim card is sim-pin2 lock. I tried this different method but none of them work:
sudo mmcli -i 0 --pin=***
error: couldn't send PIN code to the SIM: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.WrongState: Wrong state: Cannot send PIN: device is not SIM-PIN locked'
sudo mmcli -i 0 --enable
successfully enable the modem
But yet the mmcli 0 does not change
I haven't found a command to unlock sim-pin2.
In the option, there is nothing about mobile broadband. And if I plug and unplug the sim-card it says the network connection failed
I am on ubuntu 24.04

I have tried to do this also :
nmcli c add type gsm ifname cdc-wdm2 con-name  apn bicsapn
But the result was the same
